# issue with createNativeQuery when binding date type parameter

Tags: java, hibernate, binding, entitymanager

i use an EntityManager to create a nativeQuery.
My database is a Postgres database.
The date field i request is modelised like that..

```
@Column(name = "date", columnDefinition = "date", nullable = false)
private LocalDate           date;
```

when i write this, all is fine..

```
 String sqlRequest = "select insurer from stock where date='2021-01-01'";
 Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sqlRequest);
 List<Object[]> records = query.getResultList();
```

but i when i wanna use the setParameter function..

```
String sqlRequest = "select insurer from stock where date=:param";
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sqlRequest);
query.setParameter("param", "2022-03-11");
List<Object[]> records = query.getResultList();
```

i got this issue..

```
No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because you tried to set the param as String type instead of Date.

You should try to set LocalDate as time instead of "2022-03-11".

Comment: absoluty exact. made a mistake. using query.setParameter("param", reportDate); with param as LocalDate works perfectly.